# Constrain two HTML div of same size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `iframe` and I want to create another `div` as an overlay over this `iframe` for some time. Therefore, the size of that new overlay `div` and `iframe` should be same in every condition. The size of `iframe` may change for many reasons like browser window resizing, moving the splitter etc. I tried to use the `onResize` function from `jQuery` but it doesn't seem to work except for browser window resize. Could someone please suggest a way to handle all the cases?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would style them with a css class and give both (the div and the iframe) the same class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give them both a parent div with a certain width. Then maximum the content of the div for the overlay and iframe

```css
.container {
  width: 750px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
}
.overlay, iframe {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
.overlay {
  z-index: 3;
  background: #0cc;
  opacity: .7;
}
iframe {
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <iframe src="http://wikipedia.com"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Here is the same answer but the elements are responsive: http://jsfiddle.net/austinthedeveloper/crt0sdg9/